# Programar tecla ESC en JavaScript para IE 11

Tags: javascript

Buenos dias a todos, tengo un problema con un script que funciona en Chrome pero no en Internet Explorer, el script lo que hace es redireccionar cuando se pulsa el button Esc(27) usando el `event.keycode` lei que no es compatible con IE11, como podria hacer para que funcione en ese navegador y siga funcionando en Chrome?

Mi Script

```
    <script>
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 27) {
        window.location.replace("http://localhost:51213/Default.aspx");
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Capturando el evento a nivel de `document` en lugar de `body` debería funcionarte en ambos.

También deberías cambiar el `window.location.replace(url)` por `window.location.href = url':

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 27) {
      alert('Esc pulsado');
      window.location.href='https://pildorasdotnet.blogspot.com';
  }
});
```

Comment: Buenos dias Asier, funciona sin embargo no toma en cuenta el "window.location.replace" no direcciona la pagina

Comment: Deberías utilizar `window.location.href= <url>`. He editado el ejemplo para mostrarlo.

Comment: lo he intentado de esa forma, pero se queda en la misma pagina

Comment: Puedes probarlo con mi script: pulsa en "Ejecutar" y haz click en el panel blanco que se abre para que pueda capturar la pulsación del teclado, luego pulsa la tecla "Esc". Debería sacarte el mensaje y, después de cerrarlo, redireccionar a la url. Si te funciona aquí y no en tu código es que el problema estará en otra parte.

Comment: Efectivamente, funciona como me indicas pero no en mi proyecto. Seguire revisando. Gracias

Comment: Tendrias alguna idea porque podria funcionar el alert y no el redireccionamiento?

Comment: Pues no. Es raro. Puedes probarlo con las Herramientas de Desarrollo del navegador abiertas para ver si te deja algún tipo de mensaje o error en la consola

Answer (score 2):

La propiedad [`Event.keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) esta deprecada y en su lugar deberías usar [`Event.code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code)

Ejemplo:

```js
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  console.log(event.code, event.keyCode);
  if (event.code === 'Escape' || event.keyCode === 27) {
    // Aqui la lógica para el caso de Escape ...
    alert('Esc!');
  }
});
```

```html
Presiona cualquier tecla para ver el resultado
```

**PD**: `window.location.replace("http://localhost:51213/Default.aspx");` así solo no realiza ninguna acción.

Si quieres redireccionar a dicha `URL` deberías hacerlo así:

```
window.location.href = "http://localhost:51213/Default.aspx";
```

Comment: Hola Marcos, Gracias por tu respuesta. Funciona el button, el alert pero agregando el locationhref no hace el redireccionamiento

Comment: @Hans, cuando publique la respuesta tenia un error que ya corregí. Lo correcto es `window.location.href`.

Comment: Por alguna razon en el IE11 no esta redireccionando, ya realice el cambio que comentaste