# problema de logica en jquery para controlar una contraseña o si se apreta escape en el teclado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bueno el título lo dice todo, tengo una página web hecha en .ASP con Visual Basic en donde al cargar una página carga una contraseña en un campo escondido. Por otro lado tengo un input en donde la persona tiene que escribir su contraseña y lo que quiero es que cuando pierda el foco este input se ejecute una función para verificar si la contraseña es correcta, lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtpasscantidad" runat="server" TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control" onfocusout="verificarContra()" autofocus></asp:TextBox>
```

este es el input y la función es:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function verificarContra() {
    var hicontra = $('#contraseniaUsuario').val();
    var contrasenia = $('#txtpasscantidad').val();
    if (hicontra != contrasenia) {

        alert("Clave Invalida");
        $('#txtpasscantidad').focus();
        $('#txtpasscantidad').select(); 

    }
}
</script>
```

Esta es mi función básica y funciona bien, buscando información encontré el siguiente [LINK](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122625/programar-tecla-esc-en-javascript-para-ie-11) en donde hay un código con el que puedes controlar cuando se presiona la tecla escape, el código que probé en explorer y funciona es este:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
   if (event.keyCode === 27) {

   }
});
```

Pero no sé bien donde tendría que ir dentro de mi función. lo que necesito es que, si la contraseña es incorrecta pero presiono escape no muestre la alerta pero si la muestre para cualquier otro evento.

Muchas Gracias

---

Probé con lo siguiente:

```
function verificarContra() {
    var hicontra = $('#contraseniaUsuario').val();
    var contrasenia = $('#txtpasscantidad').val();
    if (hicontra != contrasenia) {
        document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 27) {

            } else {
                alert("Clave Invalida");
                $('#txtpasscantidad').focus();
                $('#txtpasscantidad').select(); 
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Pero no funciona bien, si cierro la ventana modal, que es donde tengo este formulario con el input al comenzar a escribir me salta el aviso de "Clave Invalida"

Comment: Lo que quieres haces es , que si escribes la contraseña en el campo , pero cierras el modal no te muestre la alerta de que la calve es invalidad verdad ?

Comment: eso mismo, voy a ver las respuestas igual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno te explico un poco lo que hice,

**Primero**:

Valido que si que al dar `click` en el `scape` borre los datos del campo por que si dejas datos en el campo y tienes un `blur` el va a validar y si no coinciden te va a sacar la alerta.

**Segundo**:

Valide que si el campo viene vació no haga nada no muestre nada.

Lo hice por separado prueba este **`Snippet`**, espero se de ayuda:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
   if (event.keyCode === 27) {
     $('#passwordIngresada').val('');
   }
});

 $("#passwordIngresada").blur(function() {
        var hicontra = $('#passwordIngresada').val();
        var contrasenia = $('#passwordQuemada').val();
        if(hicontra != undefined && hicontra != '' && hicontra != null){
          if (hicontra != contrasenia) {
          
                $('#mensajeEsitoso').html('');
                alert("Clave Invalida");
                $('#passwordIngresada').val('');
                 
              
          } else {
              $('#mensajeEsitoso').html('CONTRASEÑA CORRECTA , PROSEGUIR');
          }
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="password" id="passwordIngresada" />


<input  type="hidden" value="1234" id="passwordQuemada" />
<br><br>
<label id="mensajeEsitoso" style="color:green;"></label>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, me funcionó

Answer (score 0):

Quita el **onfocusout** del input y haz todo con **jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('#txtpasscantidad').on('focusout',function(e){
        var hicontra = $('#contraseniaUsuario').val();
        var contrasenia = $('#txtpasscantidad').val();
        if (hicontra.localeCompare(contrasenia) != 0) {

            alert("Clave Invalida");
            $('#txtpasscantidad').focus();
            $('#txtpasscantidad').select(); 
        }
    }); 
});
```